# Integrating with source control systems

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Following the user documentation ([Integrating with source control systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html))
we successfully set up git.

The android->native folder contains tow more
folders that are not mentioned in the user documentation: bin and gen. Is it
safe to .gitignore /apps/*/android/native/bin & /apps/*/android/native/gen

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at those 2 projects:

https://github.com/ibmmobiletipsntricks/mfp-gitignore
Those are examples of gitignores for hybrid mobilefirst project.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore
This is an example of a gitignore for android projects.

Comment: Thank you! Are thos tow folders auto re-generated on build-time?